# Will @PostConstruct on a configuration object be executed before requests are accepted in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am doing something in the @PostConstruct method in my @Configuration object in Spring MVC 4.2, will this get executed before requests are processed or is there a potential race condition there?

Answer (score 0):

When your application starts up all beans registered in the Spring context will be instantiated (including @Configuration classes) and since your application needs to have started up before you can send any requests then this post construct method will most certainly have been executed before hand.